# tree view display data using jquery javascript in yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I have display data like treeview using javascript, jquery in yii2.
I have done my code like this:

```
$this->registerJs(
  '
    function videoShow(id){
      var url = "' . Url::to(['test/get-videos-from-category']) . '?id="+id;
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function() {
          blockBody();
        },
        success:function(data){
          var hidden = $(data).find(".hidden")[0];
          var parent_id = $(hidden).find(".category_parent_id").text();
          var category_id = $(hidden).find(".category_uuid").text();
          $("span").one("click", function() {
            $(".category_video #myTab5").hide();
            $(this).parent().children().css("display","inline");
            $(this).addClass("caret-down");
            $(this).parent().parent().children().children().not($(this)).removeClass("caret-down");
            $(this).parent().children().css("display","inline").not($(this));
            $(this).parent().children().addClass("active");
          });
          var category = $(".hidden").children(".category_name").text();
          var category_uuid = $(".hidden").children(".category_uuid").text();
          var category_parent_id = $(".hidden").children(".category_parent_id").text();
          if(category == "") {
            $(".datatable-search-div").css("display","inline");
            unblockBody();
            $("#myTabContent5").css("display","inline");
            $(".showVideo").html(data);
          } else {
            if(".hidden") {
              var hidden = $(data).find(".hidden")[0];
              var hidden_category = $(hidden).find(".category_name").text();
              var hidden_parent_id = $(hidden).find(".category_parent_id").text();
              var hidden_category_uuid = $(hidden).find(".category_uuid").text();
              category = hidden_category;
              category_uuid = hidden_category_uuid;
              category_parent_id = hidden_parent_id;
              var html = "<a href=\'"+category_uuid+"\' id=\'video_search\' data-uuid=\'"+category_uuid+"\' data-parentid=\'"+category_parent_id+"\'  data-name=\'"+category+"\' data-toggle=\'tab\' class=\'caret\' onclick=videoShow(\'"+category_parent_id+"\'); style=\'margin-left: 20px;\'>"+category+"</a>";
              html += "<ul class=\'category_nested\' id=\'"+category_uuid+"\' role=\'tablist\'>";
              html += "<li class=\'category_sub_child\'>";
              html += "</li>";
              html += "</ul>";
              unblockBody();
              $("#myTabContent5").css("display","inline");
              $(".showVideo").html(data);
            }
            var html = [];
            $(".hidden").each(function(cat) {
              $("#video_search").addClass("caret-down");
              $(".category_child").parent().addClass("caret-down");
              var category = $(this).children(".category_name").text();
              ;
              var category_uuid = $(this).children(".category_uuid").text();
              var category_parent_id = $(this).children(".category_parent_id").text();
              var category_uuid_array = [];
              var category_array = [];
              var category_parent_id_array = [];
              category_uuid_array.push(category_uuid);
              category_array.push(category);
              category_parent_id_array.push(category_parent_id);
              var html_new = "<li class=\'category_child\' data-id=\'"+category_uuid+"\'>";
              html_new += "<a href=\'"+category_uuid+"\' id=\'video_search\' data-uuid=\'"+category_uuid+"\' data-parentid=\'"+category_parent_id+"\'  data-name=\'"+category+"\' data-toggle=\'tab\' class=\'caret\' onclick=videoShow(\'"+category_uuid+"\'); style=\'margin-left: 20px;\'>"+category+"</a>";
              html_new += "<ul class=\'category_nested\' id=\'"+category_uuid+"\' role=\'tablist\'>";
              html_new += "<li class=\'category_sub_child\'>";
              html_new += "</li>";
              html_new += "</ul>";
              html.push(html_new);
            });
            $(".category_child").click(function(){
              console.log("category_child clicked");
              $(this).children(".category_nested").children().html(html);
            });
            if($(".nested").length) {
              console.log("nested");
              $(".nested").children().html(html);
            }
            unblockBody();
            $("#myTabContent5").css("display","inline");
            $(".showVideo").html(data);
          }
        },
        error:function(e){
          unblockBody();
          showErrorMessage(e.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
  ', View::POS_END
);
?>
```

And html code like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="content-body"> 
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 ">
          <ul id="myUL" class="datatable-search-div" style="display: none;">
            <?php
              if (!empty($model)) {
                foreach ($model as $key => $value) { ?>
                <li class="category_video">
                  <span class="caret">
                    <a href="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>" id="video_search" data-uuid="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>"  data-parentid="<?= $value['parent_id']; ?>" data-name="<?= $value['name']; ?>" data-toggle="tab" onclick="videoShow('<?= $value['uuid']; ?>');">
                      <?= $value['name']; ?>
                    </a>
                  </span>
                  <ul class="nested" data-id="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>" id="myTab5" role="tablist" style="display:none;">
                    <li class="category_child" data-id="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>">
                      <ul class="category_nested" id="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>" role="tablist">
                        <li class="category_sub_child">
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                
                <?php
                }
              }
              ?>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content float-left  vertical col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-3 col-3 left-aligned" id="myTabContent5" style="display:none;">
    <?php
    if (!empty($model)) { ?>
        <div id="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>" class="tab-pane showVideo fade active show">
        </div>                    
    <?php
    }
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In this code `category_child` class element then that data display in that not children class.

In this code, I have tried to `Cat-1.1.1` in after `Cat-1.1` category.
But not display like that. `Cat-1.1.1` display after `Category1` and `Cat-1.1` remove.

This is an image I have to explain in the last step:

[image]
Please help if anyone have an idea for that.

Comment: images dont help much when troubleshooting add your HTML as text inside your question rather than image, and its really hard to understand what you are asking

Comment: Hi Muhammad. This is the HTML code:
<body>
  <div class="content-body"> 
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 ">
            <ul id="myUL" class="datatable-search-div" style="display: none;">
              <li>
                <a href="#" id="all_video" data-name="Allvideo" data-toggle="tab" onclick="videoAllShow();"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> All Videos</a>
              </li>
              <?php
                if (!empty($model)) {
                  foreach ($model as $key => $value) { ?>
<li class="category_video"> <span class="caret">

Comment: <a href="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>" id="video_search" data-uuid="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>"  data-parentid="<?= $value['parent_id']; ?>" data-name="<?= $value['name']; ?>" data-toggle="tab" onclick="videoShow('<?= $value['uuid']; ?>');">
                        <?= $value['name']; ?>
                      </a>
                    </span>
<ul class="nested" data-id="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>" id="myTab5" role="tablist" style="display:none;"> <li class="category_child" data-id="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>"> <ul class="category_nested" id="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>" role="tablist">

Comment: <li class="category_sub_child">
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <?php }  } ?>
</ul> </div> </div> </div> <div class="tab-content float-left vertical col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-3 col-3 left-aligned" id="myTabContent5" style="display:none;"> <?php if (!empty($model)) { ?> <div id="<?= $value['uuid']; ?>" class="tab-pane showVideo fade active show"></div> <?php}?> </div> </body>

Please help us if any solution for that. Sorry for like that answer

Comment: sir please add you code into the question by editing, not in the comments as it is unreadable

Comment: Hi Muhammad, Yes added code. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answer for my question:

```
public function getCategoryTreeHtml($level = null, $prefix = '') {

        $rows = InstrumentCategory::find()->where(['parent_id' => $level])->asArray()->all();
        $category = '';
        if (count($rows) > 0) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $sub_count = InstrumentCategory::find()->where(['parent_id' => $row['uuid']])->count();
                if($sub_count > 0){
                    $category .=  '<li style="padding: 5px;"><span class="caret"><a href="'.$row['uuid'].'" id="video_search" data-uuid="'.$row['uuid'].'"  data-parentid="'.$row['parent_id'].'" data-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-toggle="tab" onclick=videoShow("'.$row['uuid'].'");>' . $row['name'] . "</a></span>";
                    $category .=  '<ul class="nested">';

                    $category .= self::getCategoryTreeHtml($row['uuid'], $prefix . '-');

                    $category .=  '</ul>';
                    $category .=  '</li>';
                }else{

                    $category .=  '<li><a href="'.$row['uuid'].'" id="video_search" data-uuid="'.$row['uuid'].'"  data-parentid="'.$row['parent_id'].'" data-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-toggle="tab" onclick=videoShow("'.$row['uuid'].'")>' . $row['name'] . "</a></li>";
                    // Append subcategories
                    //$category .= $this->getCategoryTree($row->id, $prefix . '-');
                }
            }
        }
        return $category;
    }
```